# c, problems with using struct

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to write a program that reads text from external file (string string int, per line).
Struct is defined outside of main function:

```
typedef struct Person {
  char fname[15];
  char lname[20];
  unsigned long int birth;
} clovek;
```

I don't need "clovek" to be an array as with every line data can be overwritten.
Line is red to buffer with:

```
fgets(buffer, 50, datafile);
```

Then I want to parse it to the struct but that is where my problem arises:

```
int i = 0;
while (buffer[i] != ' ') {
  clovek.fname[i] = buffer[i];
  i++;
}
```

And this gives me out an error: expected identifier or '(' before '.' token

I also wanted to use this code for debugging but it gives out another error as well:

```
printf("fname, %s\n", clovek.fname);
```

error: expected expression before 'clovek'

My guess is that I totaly misunderstood using of struct.

Comment: All but one of the answers you got provide another frightening example of how people can get very basic C syntax wrong.

Comment: let me add another issue of complexity, element alignment in structs.  Google is your friend.

Comment: not to mention the buffer overflow waiting to happen and the lack of nul termination that makes the members of struct Person useless as C strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`clovek` is an alias for `struct Person`. Either remove the `typedef` keyword, or create an object of type `struct Person` somewhere in your code. With the present code you can do:

```
clovek someone;

while (buffer[ i ] ) != ' ') {
    someone.fname[ i ] = buffer[ i ];
/* .. */
```

Answer (score 5):

Your statement defines clovek as an alias to the structure Person.

Remove "typedef" from the declaration. This way, clovek becomes a variable of type Person:

Or even better, separate struct declaration from variable declaration:

```
struct Person {
  char fname[15];
  char lname[20];
  unsigned long int birth;
};

struct Person clovek;
```

Comment: You probably mean "struct Person clovek;" in the second line.

Comment: That should be `struct Person clovek;`